# How to remove BURG and restore GRUB?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, burg

I installed the BURG bootloader today in order to give my boot up screen some style. However, when I choose Ubuntu from the list it freezes on a screen with a bunch of code. Thankfully, I am still able to boot up Windows 7.

In my situation, how can I remove BURG and switch back to GRUB? I have a live Ubuntu USB stick, could I boot into that, purge BURG, and install GRUB again?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Dual-boot Windows 7
HP

Comment: I'm using boot-repair and have come to the part where it says to run "sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda6" apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux" when I run it it says "Unable to locate package linux" Please help! I must get this boot issue fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB drive that doesn't have any important data, I would recommend booting from an Ubuntu live system and reinstalling GRUB to your drive from there.

Watch [this video.](https://youtu.be/8lod8sRb_6I?t=30s) to find out how to do that.

It's a bit old but it is still for GRUB 2 so it should still work.
I haven't tried it though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Live USB/CD

Just let's do it from a live cd environment. Just ensure the live cd is for the same architecture as the installed system. Open up a terminal. Then, mount your / partition.

sudo su
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
Replace X with the number of partion which has your ubuntu installation.

Then, create a good environment, and use chroot:

```
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /run /mnt/run
chroot /mnt
```

If everything is OK, now you are inside your installed system, running inside a chrooted environment.

### Uninstalling The Burg Boot Loader

To remove the Burg boot loader and restore GRUB/GRUB2, then from the terminal run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove – -purge burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

To install GRUB, run these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

To install GRUB2, use these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub2
```

When you're over, hit Ctrl+D to exit the chroot environment. then, carefully umount your system, and reboot

```
umount /mnt/dev /mnt/sys /mnt/proc /mnt/run /mnt
reboot
```

Uninstalling The Burg Boot Loader

If you want to remove the Burg boot loader and restore GRUB/GRUB2, then from the terminal run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove – -purge burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

*The information for above answer was taken from [upubuntu.com](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/08/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-on.html?m=1) and [this answer](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/08/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-on.html?m=1)*