# Black screen after login on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login

I haven't used my laptop for more than a week. Today I tried to login to my existing account, but after I entered my password a black screen is shown. I waited for couple of minutes to see if anything happens, but nothing happens.

After that I turned off my laptop (by pressing the button) and turned it on. I logged in successfully with Guest User.

I also managed to login to my account by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 and logging in through terminal. I checked some suggested solutions and tried some of them, but nothing helped. I tried updating/upgrading software through terminal, but still I can't login.

I know the information I provide is very limited, but if you have any idea how I could get more information about the problem, please let me know.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is your problem similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/1008398/

Comment: @GaganRajput it's similar, but not exactly same. I don't always get "System problem detected. Do you want to report the problem now?" error. Sometimes I get the message and after that the black screen opens, other times the black screen is open immediately without any error message. Also I didn't do any updates the last time I used my laptop. And for me Ctrl + Alt + F1 works.

Comment: Why don't you try using the link given in question I provided you to fix your problem. https://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/3-ways-fix-ubuntu-gets-stuck-login-loop.html?m=1

Comment: Have you tried running an older kernel

Comment: @GaganRajput sorry for the late reply. I tried running the previous kernel by choosing "Advanced options" in the grub menu and then choosing the older version, but that didn't work out. Is that what you had in mind or should I change some config file?