# ubuntu 16.04 don't starting for the 2nd time

Tags: gnu

I'm new to Ubuntu, I was getting a problem I can't solve it, yesterday ubuntu work well but today when I turn on my pc I don't get to the login screen, just I get gnu grub screen but when I choose *ubuntu my pc It does a restart, please give me a solution I don't want to reinstall ubuntu I will lose all my files

Comment: what was the initial problem you encountered ?

Comment: I don't get to the login screen, just I get gnu grub screen but when I choose "ubuntu" or any option in "advanced options for Ubuntu"  my pc It does a restart, and I get the same gnu grub screen again.

Comment: can you recall performing any sort of update on your ubuntu OS before shutting down the system? If yes, did you check what all updates are getting installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember the last update I made, I think I will reinstall it for 3rd time, but I know well I will get the same problem again after few days, thanks

Comment: if you are dual booting your laptop, try this link if you wish to avoid any kind of hassle - `https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/`

For setting up the grub, use this command from widows: `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` 
Use it via command prompt with admin rights.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008398/ubuntu-16-04-in-boot-loop/1008772

Comment: thank you Mr  mAnN for your help, I will try it God willing

Comment: sure. let us know if you encounter any other issues.

Comment: I am very grateful to you